# Why do we add an apostrophe to "gon'"?

Tags: american-english, contractions, eye-dialect

English is not my native language, and I keep trying every day to develop my skills in it but I saw a new word of *gon'* instead of *gone*.

And I keep wondering: why do we add an apostrophe to it?

Example :

> These people gon' tell you that you won't ever make it.

Comment: I think the apostrophe is probably intended to indicate this is short for *gonna* (which itself is short for *going to*) rather than being the word *gone*. If you give us the context, we can decide whether this is correct.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence containing *gon'*? Without any context, I would guess that it's short for *gonna* or *going to*, not *gone*.

Comment: it's not common. It could represent an attempt to show a particular accent. Can you give an example?

Comment: Here is the text "These people gon' tell you that you won't ever make it"

Comment: @SugarBen: That's definitely short for *gonna*.

Comment: But why we add the apostrophe to it

Comment: The apostrophe is added because "gonna" is shortened into "gon".

Comment: Soo when we need to short a words we delete the last syllable and add apostrophe right !

Comment: Understand that "These people gonna tell you that you won't ever make it" is already very informal English, not meeting "standards" for valid syntax.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, that's right: *gonna* is nonstandard and as stigmatizing as *ain't*, while this hypothetical *gon'* is even worse doncha know.

Comment: It's not because we 'need to shorten a word', it's to show how this particular person speaks.

Comment: @KateBunting The apostrophe represents the fact that it's a shortened word. But nobody actually speaks punctuation. Even if you wanted to argue that certain punctuation does represent things like tone of voice or pauses, the apostrophe isn't a punctuation mark that has any verbal equivalent. It's only use is with written grammar. If all were were doing was writing what was said, we would write *gon*, without the apostrophe.

Comment: This is southern AmE: going to becomes "gon' ". pronounced as one syllable: goan tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The apostrophe is used to indicate missing letters relative to some standard English.

There are a number of situations where letters may be missing: There are several common contractions, such as I'm for I am, or don't for do not.  There is also the use of the apostrophe in possessives (originally also a contraction, now just a rule).

There is also the use of apostrophes to indicate a particular contracted pronunciation of a word in a dialect. I this case the speaker has contracted

> These people are going to tell you...

to "... are gonna ..." to

> These people gon tell you...

This is typical of some rural American dialects. The author wants to indicate the dialect. The apostrophe hints that letters are missing, relative to the standard spelling and help the reader work out what is being said.  In spoken English, the accent would also guide the hearer to expect this kind of contraction.

You will see various attempts by authors to write in an accent. Many accents and dialects have contractions compared to standard English. For more examples, look at JK Rowling's attempt at West Country English in [What English is this?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151218/what-english-is-this) which is analysed in greater depth in [an analysis of Hagrid's dialect](http://jurnalfahum.uinsby.ac.id/index.php/nobel/article/download/50/44/)

Answer (score 0):

Gon' or going to, or gonna...yes, correct. It's American thingy, hood version. All contractions simply accommodate a speaker for a concise, smooth, quick sentence. But in simple conversation, it's really redundant "gon'". Mostly it's used in songs, hip hop, like 6ix9ine's song "Gotti Gotti"  ...I pray to God that my family gon'(gonna) see...  So, contractions are quite helpful when it comes to rhymes, you know.